# xsl recursive loop node by index

Tags: xpath, recursion, xslt, loops, indexing

I have created a recursive template for getting the first n number of items from my XML.

It uses an index(counter) just like how I would in a for loop. Now how can I get a node from my XML using the index?

I have tried [position()=$index] but it had weird behaviour when trying to get deeper nodes in the XML hierarchy.

If I have XML such as:

```
<0>
 <1>
  <2>item</2>
  <2>item</2>
  <2>item</2>
  <2>item</2>
  <2>item</2>
  <2>item</2>
 </1>
</0>
```

I want to be able to count through and copy the 2's until I have as many as I want.

Answer (score 1):

You say you want to process your elements in groups of n. The following XSLT 1.0 solution does it:

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
  version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
>
  <xsl:param name="pGroupCount" select="3" />

  <xsl:template match="/lvl-0">
    <xsl:copy>
      <!-- select the nodes that start a group -->
      <xsl:apply-templates mode="group" select="
        lvl-1/lvl-2[position() mod $pGroupCount = 1]
      " />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="lvl-2" mode="group">
    <!-- select the nodes belong to the current group -->
    <xsl:variable name="current-group" select="
      . | following-sibling::lvl-2[position() &lt; $pGroupCount]
    " />
    <!-- output the current group, you can also do calculations with it -->
    <group id="{position()}">
      <xsl:copy-of select="$current-group" />
    </group>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to this input document:

```
<lvl-0>
 <lvl-1>
  <lvl-2>item.0</lvl-2>
  <lvl-2>item.1</lvl-2>
  <lvl-2>item.2</lvl-2>
  <lvl-2>item.3</lvl-2>
  <lvl-2>item.4</lvl-2>
  <lvl-2>item.5</lvl-2>
  <a>foo</a><!-- to prove that position() calculations still work -->
  <lvl-2>item.6</lvl-2>
  <lvl-2>item.7</lvl-2>
  <lvl-2>item.8</lvl-2>
  <lvl-2>item.9</lvl-2>
 </lvl-1>
</lvl-0>
```

The following output is generated:

```
<lvl-0>
  <group id="1">
    <lvl-2>item.0</lvl-2>
    <lvl-2>item.1</lvl-2>
    <lvl-2>item.2</lvl-2>
  </group>
  <group id="2">
    <lvl-2>item.3</lvl-2>
    <lvl-2>item.4</lvl-2>
    <lvl-2>item.5</lvl-2>
  </group>
  <group id="3">
    <lvl-2>item.6</lvl-2>
    <lvl-2>item.7</lvl-2>
    <lvl-2>item.8</lvl-2>
  </group>
  <group id="4">
    <lvl-2>item.9</lvl-2>
  </group>
</lvl-0>
```

To understand this you must know how `position()` works. When used like this:

```
lvl-1/lvl-2[position() mod $pGroupCount = 1]
```

it refers to the position of `lvl-2` nodes within their respective (!) parent. In this case, there is only one parent, so `item.0` has position 1 and `item.9` has position 10.

When used like this:

```
following-sibling::lvl-2[position() &lt; $pGroupCount]
```

it refers to the relative position along the `following-sibling::` axis. In this context, `item.1` would have a relative position of 1 in regard to `item.0`. (Basically, this is the same as the above, which just counts along the (implicit) `child::` axis.)

When used on its own, like here:

```
<group id="{position()}">
```

it refers to the position of the current node in the batch that is being processed at the moment. In our case the "batch" consists of nodes that start a group (`item.0`, `item.3`, `item.6`, `item.9`), so it goes from 1 to 4.

Answer (score 0):

I would use <xsl:for-each ... > along with position() instead of recursion.

Comment: Apologies - blindly gave the same answer as you without paying attention.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite see why you need a recursive template to do this. You could use an <xsl:for-each> to achieve this. 
(I changed the element name to make it legal)
For example:

```
<xsl:variable name='n' select='10'/>
<xsl:for-each select='two[position() &lt; $n]'>
    <!-- do whatever you need to do -->
</xsl:for-each>
```

You can use an select attribute you want and you could include an <xsl:sort> in the for-each if your input is more complex than your example.

Comment: Sorry maybe I should have added another detail. What I really want is to output the items in groups, I want to summarise the groups before they are output. But I need to group them first into a fragment tree so I can do functions on each group. This is what the loop I have does. 

So I just need to get the appropriate node according to the index. Or is this not possible? I'm a noob.

Comment: Are you using XSLT version 1 or 2? XSLT 2.0 will make that much easier I suspect - there are grouping statements in XSLT 2.0 where you need to roll your own in 1.0