# xslt transform with a count

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I'm trying to perform an xslt transform on some xml data into html. There are 3 tasks that this transform needs to do and these are:

- Sort data by date
- Output only those with a certain id
- Output only 3 of those items

So for example a snippet of my data looks like this:

```
<program id="brand_id_1">
    <date>2011-10-25</date>
    <some_info>This is some info</some_info>
</program>
<program id="brand_id_2">
    <date>2011-10-22</date>
    <some_info>This is some info</some_info>
</program>
<program id="brand_id_1">
    <date>2011-10-27</date>
    <some_info>This is some info</some_info>
</program>
```

I can order by date, I can make sure I output only the ones with the id brand_id_1, but how do I stop outputting once I've done this 3 times?

Any help, much appreciated!
Helen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sort and then check the position as for instance in the following sample:

```
<xsl:for-each select="//program[@id = 'brand_id_1']">
  <xsl:sort select="date" data-type="text"/>
  <xsl:if test="position() &lt; 4">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: +1 Dang! Beat me by 1 min ... but I corrected the sample data first ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a template and recursion to effectively create a for loop however as xslt is really just transformation tool the best thing if you can is to modify your source xml

See the answer here [xsl recursive loop node by index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1751685/xsl-recursive-loop-node-by-index)